# PyNaCl is needed but it is already installed, how to solve?

Tags: python, discord, voice, pynacl

I'm creating a discord bot and I want to get voice channel of a user.

I need to get the voice channel because I want the bot connect to the channel of the user.

I tried this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):
    VoiceChannel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    print(VoiceChannel)
    await VoiceChannel.connect()
```

This code give me this error:
"RuntimeError: PyNaCl library needed in order to use voice"

If I write in the cmd "pip install pynacl", it says:

Requirement already satisfied: pynacl in c:\users\sinia\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\sinia\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from pynacl) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.4.1 in c:\users\sinia\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from pynacl) (1.12.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\users\sinia\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=1.4.1->pynacl) (2.19)